# ReactJS code inside <div>{...}</div> not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate list and its items inside `<div>`, but for some reason the code is not rendering.

```js
<div>
 {
   sarasas.map((obj, key) => {
    console.log("cia irgi")
      return (
        <ul>
         <li>{obj.vardas}</li>
         <li>{obj.pavarde}</li>
         <li>{obj.data}</li>
         <li>{obj.klase}</li>
         <li>{obj.info}</li>
         </ul>
       )
   })
 }
</div>
```

The div shows, but everything inside it does not. This is a part of a component. Everything else works fine, I dont even know how to go about troubleshooting this. The array is not empty, and all objects inside it have all the values. Not even the `console.log` works.

Edit:
I used `console.log` to see if the array was filled with objects:

```
const sarasas = []

const updateStudentInfo = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i))
        sarasas.push(storedItems)
    }
    
    console.log(sarasas)
}
```

And it showed that there are 3 objects inside the array `sarasas`.

Comment: please share the whole code

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with the sarasas variable.. try console.log sarasas before the map

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell just based off this code, perhaps `sarasas` is an empty array or undefined. I would log or set a breakpoint to see the result of that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sarasas` is not a state, the component is not render itself after update it, so the function is not cause re-render of the component, and you still see an empty div.

To solve it, you need to define `sarasas` array as `stats`, and then each change of it will re-render the component and you'll see the new array - in this case a full array, in the div.

Comment: So i need to make/fill/update my array with useState?

Comment: yes, and change it by create new array and set the state to it

Answer (score -1):

*please try this*

***DEMO :-***

```
<div>
{
    sarasas?.map((obj) => (
         <ul>
           <li>{obj.vardas}</li>
           <li>{obj.pavarde}</li>
           <li>{obj.data}</li>
           <li>{obj.klase}</li>
           <li>{obj.info}</li>
        </ul>
    ))
}
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing persists. Everyting inside `{...}` is not rendered

Comment: there are no errors shown. not in vsc editor, console or browser

Answer (score -1):

```
render() {
    console.log('App started');
    const sarasas = [{
        vardas: 'vardas',
        pavarde: 'pavarde',
        data: 'data',
        klase: 'klase',
        info: 'info',
    }];

    return(
      <div>
      {
          sarasas.map((obj, key) => {
              console.log("cia irgi")
              return (
                  <ul>
                      <li>{obj.vardas}</li>
                      <li>{obj.pavarde}</li>
                      <li>{obj.data}</li>
                      <li>{obj.klase}</li>
                      <li>{obj.info}</li>
                  </ul>
              )
          })
        }
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.